# Fixate two sections in place in HTML/CSS/Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have divided the entire webpage into 3 sections: namely left, middle and right. I am using bootstrap so, the left and right sections have been assigned 3 cols each while the middle one 6. I want just the middle section scrollable while the other two not.

I know there is a CSS functionality of position: fixed. But it is causing my left and right section to overlap. Is there a way to fixate them besides explicitly assigning the position to it by defining left and right CSS attributes? Since, I may make changes in the future, I wish something which is more automatic.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- You need to set `height` for the `middle section`.
- Here i have set it to `500px` but you can change it as per your
  requirement.
- Set `overflow-y` to the `div` in which you have set `height` so that
  it can have vertical scroll.
- i have commented a line if you need full page height. it just for your reference.
- The class `.bg` is just to demonstrate example. you can remove it.

```css
.scrollable {
  /*height: calc(100vh - 30px);*/
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.bg {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 bg">
      Left Section
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="scrollable">
        <p>Port-salut parmesan mozzarella. Airedale blue castello blue castello fromage frais mascarpone smelly cheese pepper jack paneer. Chalk and cheese cheese and biscuits caerphilly boursin pecorino emmental cow dolcelatte. Cauliflower cheese cut the cheese stilton cheesecake cream cheese manchego chalk and cheese port-salut. Cheese triangles when the cheese comes out everybody's happy cheese and biscuits port-salut.</p>

<p>Bocconcini brie dolcelatte. Manchego danish fontina st. agur blue cheese cream cheese paneer gouda who moved my cheese say cheese. Cheese strings hard cheese bocconcini cheesy grin croque monsieur cheese slices fondue danish fontina. Cheddar fondue fromage halloumi cream cheese.</p>

<p>Gouda ricotta cow. Babybel the big cheese cut the cheese mascarpone cottage cheese swiss the big cheese taleggio. Caerphilly smelly cheese macaroni cheese cheeseburger bocconcini red leicester parmesan macaroni cheese. Cheese strings camembert de normandie stilton mascarpone cow parmesan cheese and biscuits melted cheese. Rubber cheese cheese triangles.</p>

<p>Bocconcini dolcelatte cream cheese. Boursin hard cheese fondue danish fontina everyone loves cow fromage parmesan. Babybel halloumi cream cheese swiss cow smelly cheese boursin cow. Melted cheese stinking bishop cheese on toast who moved my cheese who moved my cheese cheesy grin manchego cheese slices. Emmental goat manchego cheddar.</p>

<p>Roquefort stinking bishop everyone loves. Smelly cheese monterey jack edam gouda cheese and wine cheddar who moved my cheese edam. Cow jarlsberg who moved my cheese babybel gouda everyone loves st. agur blue cheese emmental. Blue castello goat swiss airedale cream cheese mozzarella dolcelatte brie. Blue castello danish fontina lancashire rubber cheese.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 bg">
      Right Section
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Run the snippet in full screen to have a better idea.

Comment: @Shabbir Khandwala please let me know if you need clarification or any other help.